# Encrypt and decrypt video file in JavaScript using CryptoJS

Tags: javascript, encryption, html5-video, aes, cryptojs

I would like to know how to encrypt and decrypt a video file with JavaScript. I have tried to do it with the Crypto-js library but I can't reproduce it after decrypting it. In the following code I try to take the input video to encrypt it and after decrypting it play it from HTML and download the file:

```
 input.on('change', function (e) {
      let file = e.target.files[0];
      let reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function () {
        let fileLeida = reader.result;
        let videoEncriptado = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(fileLeida, getCookie('clave')).toString();
        let videoDesencriptado = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(videoEncriptado, getCookie('clave')).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
        var videoNode = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
        let blob = new Blob([videoDesencriptado], {type: "video/mp4"});
        let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        let element = document.createElement('a');
        videoNode.setAttribute('href', url);
        videoNode.play();
        element.setAttribute('href', url);
        element.setAttribute('download', 'Blurred Bokeh Video 2.mp4');
        element.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(element);
        element.click();
        document.body.removeChild(element);

      };
      reader.readAsText(file);
});
```

Thank you in advance.

---

Code updated but still not working:

```
let file = e.target.files[0];
      let reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function () {
        var fileLeida = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(reader.result);
        console.log(fileLeida);
        let videoEncriptado = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(fileLeida, getCookie('clave'));
        let videoDesencriptado = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(videoEncriptado, getCookie('clave'));
        console.log(videoDesencriptado);
        var videoNode = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
        let blob = new Blob([videoDesencriptado], {type: "video/mp4"});
        let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        let element = document.createElement('a');
        videoNode.setAttribute('href', url);
        videoNode.play();
        element.setAttribute('href', url);
        element.setAttribute('download', 'Blurred Bokeh Video 2.mp4');
        element.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(element);
        element.click();
        document.body.removeChild(element);

      };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't convert binary data to a string because it is inherently not a string...  Anywhere in your code that you have `toString` is a mistake.

Your video file is binary data that is in video format.  Not in UTF8 format.  Why you are trying to build a string out of it is beyond me.

Comment: Should I use the method `instanceOfFileReader.readAsBinaryString(blob);` to read the file? If I pass to the encryption function anything that is not a string gives me an error.

Comment: I think that I don't finish understanding how you say that I should do it, because passing it directly the File returns error. I have added in the question the updated code, where instead of passing a string I pass a WordArray. The code still doesn't work.

Comment: Any idea how to do it, even with another library?